# Jquery autocomplete function for 2 lng

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, laravel-blade, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have 2 input,  one for ES other for EN.

```
{!! Form::text('titulo_en', null, array('placeholder' => 'Title','class' => 'form-control buscador')) !!}
{!! Form::text('titulo_es', null, array('placeholder' => 'Titulo','class' => 'form-control buscador')) !!}
```

I use jquery autocomplete and I want just to use ONE jquery function. This way I will use one function in my controler and in the future I could add any other language.

```
$(".buscador").autocomplete({
     source: "/libro/autocompletar/"+ $(this).attr('name'),
     minLength: 3,
     select: function (event, ui) {
        console.log($(this).attr('name'));  
     }
});
```

But my source appears undefinied and my console print the name correctly. I don't know how to get the input of my input field during autocomplete. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution, works for me.

```
   $(".buscador" ).focus(function() {
        var name = $(this).closest('input').attr("name");
        $(this).autocomplete({
            source: "/libro/autocompletar/"+name,
            minLength: 3,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                if(ui.item.id){
                    console.log(ui.item.id);
                }
            }
        });
    });
```